# File or directory not found error on apache 1.3 but works on apache 2.x

Tags: php, apache

So there is this problem, we have some hardware devices that are running apache servers, some older run 1.3 and newer ones run 2.X. We were updating some html/php stuff and where using relative paths in our includes

```
include_once("../stuff/other_file.php")
```

This works fine on 2.x apache servers but on the 1.3 server it returns file not found errors(even tho the file exists), i tried setting the include_path to the root directory but it still didnt work.

What did work is setting the include_once like this

```
include_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/stuff/other_file.php");
```

Which works fine on both, but the problem is that there are A LOT of files with includes on this system which would take days to go through and fix everything with this.

So why doesnt this work under apache 1.3?

Comment: Always use absolute paths. You can get the current filepath to the directory with `dirname(__FILE__)`.

Comment: @CharlotteDunois well i didnt work on this project before and its too late for that now, do i need to go over the 1000+ files now and write absolute paths everywhere?

Answer (score 0):

There can be issue with httpd and module path which is correctly defined for apache2.x but not for apache1.x. Use httpd-switcher to install 1.x from scratch. This should resolved the issue.

For more information use below command 
httpd-switcher -h

Comment: The apache or linux system on those server wont be touched just the html will be changed so i wont be able to reinstall the apache server

Comment: Please check if "AllowOverride All" is present in apache1.x configuration. for ex: <Directory "/var/www/vhosts/example.com">
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>

Comment: Couldnt find  AllowOverride in the php.ini on one of the old systems